# PDO:fetchClass not setting properties of parent class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I've got three classes:

```
class GenericObject{
    private $parentThing
}

class MiddleObject extends GenericObject{
     private $middleThing
}

class ChildObject extends MiddleObject{
     private $childThing;    
}
```

and when I call `pdoDatabaseThing->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "ChildObject");`,
all of the properties defined in MiddleObject are null, though the properties defined in ChildObject and GenericObject are set as expected.

Is this expected behavior, or am I just missing a bug somewhere in my code?  Is there a known workaround?

Comment: Please add your source codes of your php scripts. Also, read the comments on the [documentation of PDOStatement::fetchObject](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php).

Comment: I used this shorthand because the scripts are part of a pretty large custom framework.  It would be impracticable to post them.  What comment are you specifically referring to?  I don't see one that's super relevant.  I'm using fetchClass, not fetchObject.

Comment: I'm referring to the comment http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php#111744 where it may be problematic when you have a constructor since the constructor is called _after_ your values has been set in your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is an expected behavior. The `ChildObject` doesn't know about the private fields of the parent classes since they are private in that classes and thats the whole point. When the parent fields are at least `protected` you can set the field because the `ChildObject` class can use them as intended.

```
<?php
class ParentClass {
    protected $bar;

    public function getBar() {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    private $foo;

    public function getFoo() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', 'test');
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT "someValue" AS foo, "another value" as bar');
$all = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'ChildClass');
$obj = $all[0];
var_dump($obj);
var_dump($obj->getFoo(), $obj->getBar());
```

This will generate the following output:

```
object(ChildClass)#3 (2) {
  ["foo":"ChildClass":private]=>
  string(9) "someValue"
  ["bar":protected]=>
  string(13) "another value"
}
string(9) "someValue"
string(13) "another value"
```

If you change the visibility of the parents field to `private` you will get the situation you already have observed, having the parents private fields still be at `NULL`:

```
object(ChildClass)#3 (3) {
  ["foo":"ChildClass":private]=>
  string(9) "someValue"
  ["bar":"ParentClass":private]=>
  NULL
  ["bar"]=>
  string(13) "another value"
}
string(9) "someValue"
NULL
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually figured the same thing out late yesterday.  It was my mistake making them private instead of protected.  If anyone in makes the same mistake, the real issue here is that, since PDO does some kind of under the hood array/map/object voodoo in setting object properties, it won't throw an error when you try to set private members that should be protected.  It will simply create NEW properties of the object while leaving the private ones null, as in your example.  The API of our framework was scrubbing out those new properties and leaving me only the null ones on the client.